# Append to closest - for each : pattern repeated

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm looking to append each of the 'content' divs to the nearest, higher div of class .cf-container

The pattern is repeated several time throughout the document.

Can this be done with jQuery?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `.cf-container` is always a previous sibling of `.content`:

```
$(".content").each(function() {
  let _this = $(this);
  _this.prev(".cf-container").append(_this);
});
```

If there would be other siblings between `.content` and `.cf-container`

```
$(".content").each(function() {
  let _this = $(this);
  _this.prevAll(".cf-container").first().append(_this);
});
```